# Wrapped sql.DB by struct can't invoke methods in instance

Tags: go

My goal is using a struct to wrap sql.DB to do something more than sql.DB.
The instance I create can't work and give me this error when I run it.

```
DbConn.db.prepare undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method sql.(*DB)."".prepare)
```

My code is:

```
type DatabaseConn struct {
  driverName string
  databaseName string
  userName string
  password string
  dataSourceName string
  db *sql.DB
}

func (d DatabaseConn)Open() error {
    d.driverName    = DB_DRNAME
    d.userName      = DB_UNAME
    d.password      = DB_PWD
    d.databaseName  = DB_DBNAME
    d.dataSourceName = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@/%s?charset=utf8",d.userName, d.password, d.databaseName)
    db, err := sql.Open(d.driverName, d.dataSourceName)
    return err
}


func (d *DatabaseConn)Close() error {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Trying to handle error in DatabaseConn.Close(): ", err)
        }
    }()

    err := d.db.Close()
    return err
}
```

I am trying to create an instance and invoke sql.DB method.

```
var dbConn DatabaseConn
dbConn.Open()
defer dbConn.Close()
dbQuery := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT *, FROM ms_node WHERE node_id = ?")
getNodeRecord, err := dbConn.db.prepare(dbQuery)
```

The error message is pointed here.

```
./server.go:343: dbConn.db.prepare undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method sql.(*DB)."".prepare)
```

(Personal background: I am newbie for 2 weeks)

Comment: Is all of this code within the same package? You should also remove your use of `defer` - it doesn't help make your code clearer or safer.

Comment: @elithrar Yes. I guess they are in one package, as they are in one .go file. I guess something wrong with the pointer and the instance. But I can't tell there the problem is. Sorry, I didn't clean defer out. I do it right now.

Comment: I think you want sql.Open to assign to d.db, not just db. Also possible sql syntax error: *,

Comment: Sorry! I forgot paste these functions into question. I do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`Prepare`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) starts with a capital letter ;)

So you should have:

```
getNodeRecord, err := dbConn.db.Prepare(dbQuery)
```

Comment: I spent hours to find this bug! THANK YOU!